# Get result of useQuery with Apollo and Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo, pinia

I'm trying to use the `useQuery` function (from package `'@vue/apollo-composable'`).

This function doesn't return a promise, just refs to `result`, `loading` etc. so I can't directly use this data in my store (Pinia).

**Currently I have this code:**

```js
fetchArticle: function (id: string) {
      // check if article is already in cache
      const cache = this.articles.find(a => a.id == id);
      if (cache && !cache.partial) return cache;
      // fetch article from server
      const { result: article } = useQuery<{ article: Article }>(GET_ARTICLE, { id });
      // update state, but... when `article` contains data? 
    },
```

When I'am in a store I don't know how to wait for request end.

I tried to transform `useQuery` to return promise but that doesn't work, Nuxt.js freeze on server with this code:

```js
fetchArticle: async function (id: string) {
      // check if article is already in cache
      const cache = this.articles.find(a => a.id == id);
      if (cache && !cache.partial) return cache;
      // fetch article from server
      const { onResult, result } = useQuery<{ article: Article }>(GET_ARTICLE, { id });
      const article = result.value?.article || (await new Promise(r => onResult(({ data }) => r(data.article))));
      if (!article) return;
      const data = { ...article, partial: false };
      this.articles = this.articles.map(a => (a.id == id ? data : a)) as Article[];
      // return article
      return article;
    },
```

**Informations**

- Store: Pinia
- Versions: Nuxt 3.1.2; @vue/apollo-composable 4.0.0-beta.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the apollo client like this:

```
// The creation of the client
// This part is on a base class, that all of my Service extends
this.apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: //the link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  name: "My APP name",
  version: `v${version.toString()}`,
  defaultOptions: defaultOptions //some options I customize
});
provideApolloClient(this.apolloClient);

//The query
// This part is on the Service class
return this.apolloClient.query({ query: query, variables: { id: id }}).then((result) => {
  return result.data.myData;
});
```

I always used like this, never used the **useQuery**. In the link I use a combination of three, one for the Auth, one for Errors and one for the base URL